# Equivalent "completion handler" from MagicalRecord to Realm.io

Tags: ios, block, magicalrecord, realm, completion

I searched for a many days, but I can not find it. What would be the equivalent of the following MagicalRecord statement in Realm.io?

```
[MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    // Save block

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    // Completion block

}];
```

I need **"Save block"**, and when it finish, execute **"Completion block"**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the equivalent in Realm is [`-[RLMRealm transactionWithBlock:]`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/transactionWithBlock:).

Since both your MagicalRecord example and Realm's equivalent run in the current thread, the completion block is a bit redundant because it's equivalent to adding code immediately after the call to this method.